# Unable to install yum on Ubuntu 20.04 (AWS EC2)

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum

My command is `sudo apt-get install yum`

The result is ：

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package yum
```

Comment: `yum` is for RedHat style Linux distributions that uses rpm-packages and not normally needed in Ubuntu. In Ubnuntu `apt` is used instead. It is not recommended for normal users to try to install RedHat (rpm) packages in Ubuntu.

Comment: AWS EC2 need use yum to install s3fs in order to mount S3 bucket. So I must install yum. I try it successful. Thanks~

Comment: I don't think you really need yum to install s3fs. Ubuntu's official repository does have s3fs package which can be installed using `sudo apt install s3fs`.

Answer (score 0):

I try it successful.

I must install rpm first：

```
sudo apt-get install rpm
```

And then install the yum：

```
sudo apt-get install yum
```

Comment: I can't install YUM even after installing RPM. Did you add something in sources.list or some PPA?

Comment: After initializing AWS EC2,I execute these instructions：

sudo apt install chrony   // for time sync

sudo /etc/init.d/chrony restart  // restart chrony

sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata  //set timezone

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common  

sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ethereum

sudo apt-get install rpm

sudo apt-get install yum 

That's it.

Comment: same error after all above command run.

Comment: this didn't work for me either. sudo apt-get install yum still returns E: Unable to locate package yum